# Use @WebFilter from another library without web.xml

Tags: java, web-applications, java-ee-6, java-ee-8

I have a webfilter shared between all my webapps.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/*")
public class ApiOriginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ... do something
    }
}
```

Let's say `ApiOriginFilter` belongs to package org.commons.

Now my **webapp.ear** imports a common library with `ApiOriginFilter`.
To make the filter work properly, I had to include it into **web.xml**, because it seems that if filter belongs to another library it's not enabled by default.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.commons.filter.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is there any way to make it work without declaring in *web.xml* ?

Comment: Have you tried packaging it in `WEB-INF/lib` rather than in `ear/lib`?

Comment: actually not, however is not the best solution to me because common library is also needed by ejb module, for example

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the web module annotation-scans web-inf/lib only.